# __try and __except not working in Release build

Tags: c++, seh

In my program i really need to use SEH exception handlers, which catch errors like AccessViolation & etc., but handlers work only in Debug build.

I have enabled same option in Release build, but it does not work.

How to enable SEH in Release mode ANYWAY?

Thank you!

```
__try { /* crash code */ }
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER { MessageBox("Crash prevented"); }
```

Works in Debug build mode, but not in Release (crashes).

Comment: There's nothing special about SEH in a Release build.  Nobody can guess what "it does not work" might mean if you don't describe what you see going wrong and don't post a snippet.

Comment: @Hans Passant Relax. If you need special explanation: my program in debug mode handles SEH exceptions (handler works), in release mode simply no. Configuration is the same at most, except base Release/Debug modes difference.

Comment: Okay LOLs, it is time to close the question as "Offtopic" or "Not constructive"!

Comment: This is a very valid question. The same happens to me. What more explanations do you need? Your code creates for example an AccessViolation C0000005 and the exception is NOT caught in the __except() block. While this works in DEBUG builds it does not in RELEASE builds. I cannot see what should be "offtopic" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing with settings more i have found the solution.
In Release config i had to activate "Basic Run-time checks" in page "Code generation" to enable SEH exception handlers.

"Basic Run-time checks" option cannot be used with any optimization enabled.

Comment: Hello Loryan, I am reproducing crash occurs on Windows 10 x64. but not in Windows 7 x64

Comment: This answer is wrong. I have release builds where "Run-time checks" are off and the SEH handler is working perfectly. SEH exceptions are generated by the processor and cannot be turned off in the compiler. Surely your problem is the crash code itself beeing optimized away in a Release build. So I suppose that your code which should crash your application simply does not exist anymore in the Release build. Call the following function: BOOL Crash() { static int* NullPtr = NULL; return NullPtr[4]; } The compiler cannot optimze this away. It will crash your app, also in a Release build.